# Close the Immediate Window - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

With the VBA window active, I can open the Immediate Window *(really a pane)* in two ways:

- **with the mouse** - on the Menu Bar - *View > Immediate Window*
- **with the keyboard** - touch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd>

I can close the Immediate Window with the mouse by clicking the red "x" at the Window's upper right-hand corner.

How can I close the Immediate Window *(only the bottom pane)* using only the keyboard *(without the mouse)* ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's really a window (not longer a command) you can use Alt+F4 (close active instance) like any other application ***(as long as its the active window)***
**UPDATE:** 
You may try Ctrl+F4 -close active window of the instance- (if it's not docked).
If it's docked, it belong to the instance of vba itself, so, I'm not quite sure how would you call the element to take it off from the dock and then close it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but on my computer `Alt + F4` shuts down the entire VBA window rather than just the Immediate Window *(pane)*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent This won't work in the docked/pane state, but it will once you undock it. And `Ctrl+G` will reopen it in an undocked state, which you can once again close with `Alt+F4` if you use `Ctrl+G` to make it the active panel.

Comment: @Sgdva..........Nice idea...............I have never tried to un-dock these "panes"................I now see that sometimes "panes" can be "pains"

Answer (score 7):

You could write a macro for this :)

Have this code in a standard module (requires programmatic access to the VBIDE API):

```
Public Sub CloseImmediatePane()
    Application.VBE.Windows("Immediate").Close
End Sub
```

Programmatically closing the immediate pane from the immediate pane will only make it flicker (close and come back), so you can't run this macro from the immediate pane... but you can place your cursor inside the procedure and hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, and it works, docked or not!

<sub>Funky creative ideas are allowed, right?</sub>

Comment: Thanks!!........................ *(and I can assign keystrokes to your sub and avoid the mouse)*

Comment: Ha! didn't think of that!

Comment: This works with the object itself (so doesn't matter if dock able or not dock able) so +1

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer.  `Application.VBE.Windows("Immediate").Visible = False` also works, and thus you can open / show the Immediate window with `Application.VBE.Windows("Immediate").Visible = True`

Comment: I got an error `Object variable or With block variable not set`. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @YasserKhalil have you enabled programmatic access to the VBE object model? `Application.VBE` might be `Nothing` if it's disabled.

Comment: Yes and this solved the problem. How can I make the immediate window active to clear its contents of it?